# Access to SQL Server export date/time encoding bug

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, odbc, export

When I export my tables from MS Access 2007 to SQL Server 2014 via ODBC driver, all tables go normally, but for tables when include date/time field generate code follows:

```
... "tt" datetime2(⪎Ѱ�撵)
```

These characters don't copypast in the message (screenshot from profiler https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwxVH.png)

When I convert date/time to string on my Access, all export normally.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your fields in SQL Server are of data type DateTime2, change these to DateTime.

Comment: I export from MS Access 2007, there is only one date/time type.

Comment: Yes, in Access. But SQL Server has two. Perhaps the wrong is selected. Are you using the upsize wizard? It usually does it right.

Comment: I use right click on table -> export -> ODBC database.

Comment: On upsize wizard I get "upsize wizard don't support your SQL server".

Comment: Ah, yes, that is correct. If you manually create the table and fields in SQL Server you should be able to append the records. If not, you may have to launch SSMS, SQL Server Management Studio. It will do the job.